# About new PrintWriter(writer w, boolean autoflushable);

Tags: java, io, printwriter

Here from the java doc:

> PrintWriter
>
> public PrintWriter(Writer out,
>                      boolean autoFlush)
>
> ```
> Creates a new PrintWriter.
>
> Parameters:
>     out - A character-output stream
>     autoFlush - A boolean; if true, the println, printf, or format methods will flush the output buffer
> ```

I would like to know if creating a `PrintWriter` with this constructor actually wrap the `OutputStream` will be buffered or not.

Here is the source code I found in [this website](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintWriter.java#PrintWriter.%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.Writer%29) (grepcode) and here I report the class constructor in question:

> Creates a new PrintWriter.
>
> Parameters:
>       out A character-output stream
>       autoFlush A boolean; if true, the println, printf, or format methods will flush the output buffer.
>
> ```
>   public  [More ...] PrintWriter(Writer out,boolean autoFlush) {
>       super(out);
>       this.out = out;
>       this.autoFlush = autoFlush;
>       lineSeparator = java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
>       new sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction("line.separator"));    }
> ```
>
> Creates a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing, from an
>   existing OutputStream. This convenience constructor creates the
>   necessary intermediate OutputStreamWriter, which will convert
>   characters into bytes using the default character encoding.
>
> Parameters:
>       out An output stream See also:
>       java.io.OutputStreamWriter.OutputStreamWriter.(java.io.OutputStream)
>        public  [More ...] PrintWriter(OutputStream out) {
>            this(out, false);
>        }

Note that the `super(out)` it's only needed for synchronization purposes.(source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/Writer.java#Writer.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.Object%29)) 
There is no reference of using a `BufferedWriter` as there is for all the other constructors of the `PrintWriter` class.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223211/is-a-printwriter-a-bufferedwriter) question I have been told that this constructor does not seem to use a buffer, however when using it it clearly use a buffer (ie without specifying `true` in the second parameter it does not flush and flushing is applicable only to buffers.

Moreover, I have seen code written like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747040/difference-between-java-io-printwriter-and-java-io-bufferedwriter):

```
 PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
                         new BufferedWriter (
                             new FileWriter("somFile.txt")));
```

Which could be replace by `PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("someFiles.txt",true));` without wrapping the `FileWriter` in a buffer.

Bottom line I would like to know if `new PrintWriter(writer w, true);` is automatically wrapped in a buffer like all the other constructor are. If so could you please indicate the bit of source code where it happens?

Comment: Well, `System.out` is a `PrintWriter`; if you `.print()` (not `.println()`) and do not `.flush()`, the output does not appear

Comment: @fge I have never had the need to flush a System.out.print();

Comment: While flushing is only applicable to buffered streams/writers, that doesn't mean it's *unsupported* - on unbuffered streams it's a no-op. (See [`OutputStream.flush()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush())) Setting `autoflushable` to `true` only says that the `PrintWriter` will call flush on whatever it's been told to wrap - it doesn't need to care that doing so is pointless, and also doesn't need to add buffering. Basically: "buffering" and "flushability" are independent properties of a stream. Related, but the latter doesn't require or imply the former.

Comment: @millimoose the thing is that if I set a PrintWriter(writer out, false), it gets out of the stream only if I then invoke flush(). So it suggests that it actually gets buffered.

Comment: @Rollerball Remember that the underlying operating system is also free to do buffering - buffering output on the Java side is to avoid the overhead of doing a system calls for every character/byte written. You also never say what the underlying `Writer` is. All I'm saying is the buffering doesn't *need* to happen at the outermost `PrintWriter`, and it certainly doesn't seem to when you construct it from another `Writer`.

Comment: @Rollerball It's true that `PrintWriter` does add buffering in the other cases as a performance improvement, and this makes sense for a `PrintWriter` since the point is to write whole Strings, not characters. I can't tell you why that one constructor is the exception, only that it is.

Comment: @millimoose Ok so the OS buffer waits a flush call from a higher level (java side) to flush the output?

Comment: @Rollerball I have... You probably use a non buffered console, mine is

Comment: @Rollerball It *might*. All I'm trying to say is that just because there is no buffer in the `PrintWriter`, that doesn't mean that there is no buffer anywhere between your code and the target output. And `flush()` usually flushes any and all output buffers in the chain.